What is bhat from emmeans in clm ordinal models? And how does it relate to the model coefficients?
I am researching how ordinal models work in conjunction with marginal means. I am stuck with understanding a particular part of the emmeans output, specifically what bhat contains when building an ordinal model.
I assume from the name, and other documentation, that it is something to do with the model coefficients, but I can't see what their relationship is in the example I am working through.
Here is an example, showing some fake data and the relationship I was expecting, but can't find.
library(ordinal)
library(emmeans)

n = 100
df = data.frame(y = sample(1:5, size = n, replace = TRUE),
                x = sample(0:1, size = n, replace = TRUE))
df$y = factor(df$y)
df$x = factor(df$x)

fit = clm(y ~ x, data = df)

marginal = emmeans(fit, ~ y | x, mode = "prob")

marginal@bhat
coef(fit)

I was expecting to find some relationship between the bhat vector and the coefficients of the model. There are 5 model coefficients, but 8 bhat values. I understand that the bhat values are combinations of the coefficients. But I can't figure out what combination that would be.
Any advice on this or for relevant resources is appreciated.

I don't know much about this type of model (and don't have time to go through the paper) but "Estimated marginal means or EMMs (sometimes called least-squares means) are predictions from a linear model over a reference grid". Check out predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(x = factor(c(0, 1))), type = "cum.prob")

This is an ordinal logistic model, so we assume that there exists a latent variable $Y^*$ which is not observed directly. Instead, we observe
$$
Y=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if} &Y^*\leq\alpha_{1|2} \\
2 & \text{if} & \alpha_{1|2}<Y^*\leq\alpha_{2|3} \\
\vdots
\end{cases}
$$
We then have $Y^*=\beta X + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ follows a standard logistic distribution.
coef(fit) displays the estimates of the cutpoints $\alpha_{j|(j+1)}$ and the slope $\beta$, e.g., $\hat{\alpha}_{1|2}=-1.4557432$ and $\hat{\beta}=-0.1445302$.
The bhat values correspond to estimated cumulative probabilities. For example, if you want to estimate $\Pr(Y \leq 2|X=1)$, you have
$$
\Pr(Y \leq 2|X=1) = \Pr(Y^*\leq\alpha_{2|3} |X=1) = \Pr(\beta + \epsilon \leq\alpha_{2|3})= \Pr(\epsilon \leq\alpha_{2|3}-\beta)
$$
Our estimate of $\alpha_{2|3}-\beta$ is $-0.3277077$. Plugging this into the logistic CDF gives a probability of plogis(-0.3277077)=0.4187985.
You can do this for all possible combinations of $Y$ and $X$ to obtain all the values in bhat.
